# Where does ProcessBuilder or Runtime classes get the environment variables from?

Tags: java, windows, process, processbuilder

This link: [Understanding Java Process and Java ProcessBuilder](https://www.developer.com/java/data/understanding-java-process-and-java-processbuilder.html) has a sentence saying that Process created by the exec method doesn't own a console.

If I'm calling a python script from the java, where does the Process pickup the environmental variables from?

How can I manipulate/add/remove environmental variables which are used by Java Process class?

Comment: [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) says (in part) *an environment, which is a system-dependent mapping from variables to values. The initial value is a copy of the environment of the current process (see System.getenv()).* You should check the Javadoc when confused.

Comment: In general, processes inherit their parent's environment by default, with the option to apply changes if desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ProcessBuilder.environment()` method to get a `Map` of the environment variables.

**[`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#environment())** docs state that:

> Returns a string map view of this process builder's environment.
>   Whenever a process builder is created, the environment is initialized
>   to a copy of the current process environment (see System.getenv()).
>   Subprocesses subsequently started by this object's start() method will
>   use this map as their environment.

Using the returned map you can set your own custon env variables which will be used by the process you started.

The sample snippet below, demonstrates the setting of env variables using `ProcessBuilder` API:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     ProcessBuilder pb =
                new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "echo", "%JAVA_HOME%");
     Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
     env.put("JAVA_HOME", "c/User/Programs/JDK...");
     Process p = pb.start();
     BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
     String line = "";
     while((line=br.readLine()) != null){
         System.out.println(line);
     }
     try {
         int exitValue = p.waitFor();
         System.out.println("\n\nExit Value is " + exitValue);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```